# What is a real unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

So for a while now I've been pondering what a real unit test should consist of. It's best to demonstrate this with an example, here's my angular service I want to test:

```
function stringUtils() {
    return {  
        splitFilterString: splitFilterString
    } 

    function splitFilterString (filterString) {
        return filterString.split(':');
    }
}
```

I've been thinking which of my 2 approaches best describes a "real" unit test for `splitFilterString`. (The examples are written with jasmine)

## 1 Test that `String.prototype.split` has been called.

You don't test any "real" examples with this, you just test that the function actually calls `String.prototype.split` and returns whatever that function returns. This has been my way of testing so far because you don't test "external" API's for doing what they tell you they (should) be doing.

```
    it('should call split with ":" as an argument and return whatever split returns', function () {
        var filterString = 'foo:bar';
        spyOn(String.prototype, 'split').and.returnValue('foo');
        expect(stringUtils.splitFilterString(filterString)).toBe('foo');
        expect(String.prototype.split).toHaveBeenCalledWith(':');
    });
```

## 2 Test for the actual expected output of the function.

I also like this approach because you test for actual input/output how the function is meant to be used. On the downside you're indirectly testing `String.prototype.split` here as well, you're testing if it actually does what it says it does.

```
    it('should return the correct output', function () {
        expect(stringUtils.splitFilterString('foo:bar')).toEqual(['foo', 'bar']);
        expect(stringUtils.splitFilterString('foobar')).toEqual(['foobar']);
    });
```

Comment: I don't see any point in testing whether the internals work or not. It doesn't make any difference as long as the output is correct. The entire point of unit testing is that you can mess around with the internals as much as you like and the unit tests confirm that the functionality stays correct.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what "you don't test "external" API's for doing what they tell you they (should) be doing" means. That is totally the way you test APIs, external or not.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but I would go for approach 2. You want to test the expected output of your function, not what it calls under the hood. A future developer could refactor the code to call a different function and this would result in failure of all your test in approach 1 without having any effect on the application that uses it.

Comment: @Juhana if you're testing third party API's, for example testing that `$state.go('someState')` changes `$state.current` to `'someState'` you're doing integration tests imo

Comment: Also, to whoever downvoted this post, feel free to tell me why so I can improve my original post.

Comment: @NexusDuck You don't generally unit test 3rd party APIs. It's their job.

Comment: @Juhana That's exactly my point. But with your second comment you seem to be implying that I should test for it. Perhaps I just misunderstood.

Comment: I just pointed out that either I don't understand what you're trying to say with that sentence or your logic of "you don't test 3rd party APIs like this so you shouldn't test your own code like this either" is flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are coupling the test with the implementation, that's the main difference.

This might get in your way later on if you find out that there's a `superFastSplit` that you want to use, because you need to change your code **and** your test.
So in this case the test is not providing real value because it might hold you back when you want to refactor: "I want to refactor that portion of code, but those damn tests mean I have to do everything **twice**!".

In the second example you are testing behaviour, so your code will allow you to use `superFastSplit` because you are not interested in how you get to your result, you are interested that the result is consistent across implementations.

**EDIT** After OP comment

In the case of an external API I would still follow the "don't harm my future self / colleague" path, so I would do the easiest thing, which IMHO is to use a module that mocks the external API, something like this:

```
nock('http://external.api.com')
  .get('/end/point')
  .reply(200);
```

Of course you have to be careful and don't try to cover too many scenarios, because you are basically deciding what the external API will return, so I would say I would just test the ok and nok scenarios here, and cover all the details in an integration test.

Under the covers what [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) does is:

> Nock works by overriding Node's http.request function. Also, it overrides http.ClientRequest too to cover for modules that use it directly.

You can always test for any side effect that the API call has in your code, but I feel that that approach is more difficult to follow when applying TDD.

Comment: I like your answer, but what if for example as the result of your function you call an external API that hasn't got any output, do you test for the external API being called or do you test for the result of what the external API should be doing? (for example after calling `$state.go('someState')` testing that `$state.current === 'someState'`

Comment: Thanks, but I meant calling an external API that does not have any return value (like `void` methods in Java for example).

Comment: It will return something right? At least the status code should be there. If you don't receive any response at all I don't think the HTTP protocol can consider the call done, so I think that's a scenario that it's not possible. What do you think?

Comment: Some functions don't return anything, like most routing functions in angular. I'm not just talking about HTTP calls

Comment: Ah ok sorry, now I got it. If the function does not return anything but there are side effects I would probably check those, if it does not return anything and there are no side effects I see little choice here :D I would go for your option #1